# Is it possible to read NetCDF file above 1 GB using SRdd?

Tags: scala, netcdf

we are using SciSpark for reading NetCDF file using the concept of SRdd. We are getting error once we tiring to read above 1gb file.

val data = sc.OpenPath("/home/Project/TestData",List("rhum"))

is there any problem in this code ?

getting error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, SciSpark is Spark library and you run your code with `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`. If so, you just need specify proper memory options, like this:

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 8g
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy Kotlyarenko... But how to apply this 
spark-shell --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 8g in this context

Comment: It depends on how you run your code. Are you use spark-submit or another script?

Comment: Its working with small datasets but getting error above 1 gb files.                    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("test11")
    conf.set("spark.executor.memory","12g")
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
    conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SciSparkContext(conf)